# "Upgrade: websocket" header is removed from SockJs Websocket connection request, sent only from an specific user laptop

Tags: websocket, http-headers, sockjs

We are using sockJs to initiate a Websocket connection in our client side javascript app.

We are having an issue with a websocket request, initiated only from a specific client's machine.
The request initiated via this machine doesn't contain below two headers. We expect these two headers to be initiated with the request.

```
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: upgrade
```

Seems like these two headers are removed from some client machine specific configuration (proxy or firewall)

What could be the reason for this.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @Martin We found out, due some kind of a machine specific config, the mentioned machine doesn't support websocket connections.